# How to Open Terminal Window Automatically on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

On my Mac, there is no window open when I start Terminal app. I just played with a friend's Mac, a window is automatically opened on startup of terminal. He doesn't know how it's done. I just played with preferences and couldn't find anything for that. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I think I might have found the problem. The suggestion works on another Mac. I compared it with mine. I have something called Visor installed. That may be interfering with the opening of the terminal.

Comment: Yes, Visor “grabs” the first window created and uses it for its own purposes, leaving you without an initial terminal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Windows Group
2. Go to Preferences -> Start, and select the windows group to open on start up

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't work for me. I still have to open new window manually.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer if the OP says it didn’t work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm just grasping at straws here: is it possible that your Terminal program is always running in the background, and you are not actually completely exiting? You can perform this test: Run Terminal in whatever manner you usually do, and then press Command-Q to quit the application completely. Now run Terminal again. Did it open a new window?

The Mac has a slightly different paradigm on open/closed applications, namely that closing the last window doesn't actually quit the application. Combine this with the fact that Mac users rarely ever actually reboot their computers, and it's easy for relatively novice Mac users to have many applications that are simply running in the background that are never closed completely.

Just a shot in the dark. If you are for sure exiting the app completely than I can't think of a solution for the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

From the Terminal App, choose Preferences: select Startup and verify that the "On startup, open new window with settings:" radio button is selected and select Basic from the pull-down menu. That's all I have and it starts up with an open window for me.

Comment: I guess something is messed up on my Mac. This doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried all the above suggestions, see if anything weird is appearing in your console. Open up /Applications/Utilities/Console.app and watch the "All Messages" log while you open Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the other terminal apps that are out there for Mac. I prefer iTerm, it's free and works very well. It also gives you nice features like tabs, color schemes and fullscreen terminals.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this out, it is a Ruby gem that lets you automate opening mutliple tabs that run preset scripts or commands: https://github.com/Achillefs/elscripto